# Equivalence of two expected value terms and the distribution of its parameters

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, expected-value, parameter-estimation

**Problem:**

"The number of breakdowns $Y$ per day for a certain machine is a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda$. The daily cost of repairing these breakdowns is given by $C=3Y^2$. If $Y_1,...,Y_n$ denote the observed number of breakdowns for $n$ independently selected days, find an MVUE for $E(C)$. Use the Rao-Blackwell Theorem."

While looking over a solution manual to check my answers in a statistics textbook, I stumbled across the following work. How does one go from the second statement to the last?

$E(\frac{3}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^nY^2_i | \frac{\Sigma_{i=1}^nY_i}{n})$

[image]

Comment: Please add some context...what is $Y$, what are $Y_i$'s etc.

Comment: @StubbornAtom added the problem's prompt

Comment: Is this chapter 9 exercise maybe 59 in the book by Dennis Wackerly, William Mendenhall, and Richar Scheaffer? If so, you might be interested in [this in-site post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301606) and another [post in the statistics site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201721). Now, your problem is specific to this solution you "stumbled across". Would you might including the snapshots of the entirety of said solution? From what I'm seeing, there might be something wrong with this solution.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem I am looking at. I just do not understand how they go from the second to the third statement. @LeeDavidChungLin